# Navigation bar between activities

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

I use this code to hide the navigation bar. The problem is that when I go into a different activity the navigation bar pop out and hides itself again (happens in less than a second) which I don't like. How do I prevent it from poping out. Is there another way to hide it.

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView()
                    .setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this in onCreate() prevent it from poping out.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You create one class and hide navigation bar there.And then extend this class in other two class.As a result you should use inheritence.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```